# add the_post_thumbnail as CSS Background, in wordpress theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am trying to set my featured image as a background image in CSS.

I need to show the same featured image in two places in the HTML and CSS.

How do you use `the_post_thumbnail()` in CSS?

**HTML**

```
 <div class="magnify">
    <div class="large"></div>
    <img class="small" <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'large', array
    ('class' =>'img-      responsive') ); ?> />
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.large {background: url('img/image.jpg') no-repeat;}
```

Comment: You'll need to use inline CSS for this - eg `style="background-image: ......."` on your HTML element - as you can't get the PHP value into the CSS.

Comment: plz comments complete code with wordpress query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Tim Malone stated in the comments, you will need to do this with **inline styles**. You can do something like this:

```
<?php
$thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large');
list($url, $width, $height, $is_intermediate) = $thumbnail;
?>

<div class="large" style="height:<?php echo $height; ?>px;background-image:url(<?php echo $url; ?>);background-repeat:no-repeat;"></div>
```

Note that I am using `wp_get_attachment_image_src` so that I can get the image dimensions in case I need them. In this case, it is to set the height of the div to the height of the image.

Comment: @FarooqAhmad Thanks, I added `background-repeat:no-repeat;`

Comment: @FarooqAhmad You can also add `background-repeat:no-repeat;` to your css file since it doesn't depend on php. You can do `.large {background-repeat: no-repeat;}`